# Complex analysis, evaluating a path integral

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Evaluate the integral

$\int_{\gamma}e^{z^2}+ \overline{z} \ \ dz,   $

where $\gamma$ is the positively oriented unit circle.

Comment: What steps have you taken to solve the problem?

Comment: Im guessing the path is something like $\gamma (t)=e^{it}$ with $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$

Comment: Have you tried that out?

Comment: Yeah but the i get stuck with an $e^{e^{2it}}$ term and im not sure where to go then?

Comment: Do you that the integral along a loop of a function analytic on and inside that loop vanishes?

Comment: I get to $\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{e^{2it}}+e^{-it})ie^{it}dt$ and then am in a bit of a pickle?

Comment: Sorry I am not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: Let $\gamma$ be a closed loop. $\gamma$ bounds a region $U$. If on a domain $D\supset \gamma\cup U$, $f$ is analytic, then$\int _{\gamma} f(z) dz=0$. Do you know this result?#

Comment: Yes thank you Montez, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int_\gamma e^{z^2} + \overline{z} \; \mathrm{d}z= \int_\gamma e^{z^2} \; \mathrm{dz}+\int_{\gamma} \overline{z} \; \mathrm{d}z$$
For the first one use that $e^{z^2}$ is holomorphic (so what is the value of the integral)? 
for the second use a parametrisation of the unit circle.

Just cause i like it, you can use that for $|z|=1$ the following equlity holds
$$\frac{1}{z}=\overline{z}$$

Comment: Thats very helpful, taking a look a holomorphic functions now and it all makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Set $z=e^{i\theta}$ for $0\leq\theta<2\pi$ and notice $dz=ie^{i\theta}d\theta$.